# Windows Server backup 2008 R2 error

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, backup

I'm trying to set up a Windows Server backup on a Server 2008 R2 box to a remote server on a different subnet. The server being backed up is on a domain, the remote server is in a workgroup dedicated to backup storage. There is a local user account set up on the remote server similar to the domain account backing up the server.

Trying to set up the backup I get to the credentials box, and then get the error "Windows Server Backup is unable to access the remote shared folder. Logon Failure: the specified account password has expired". I have checked the account, it is set to never expire. I have even reset the password to make sure this is correct.

On the remote server, in the security logs I'm getting:

```
Log Name:      Security
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
Date:          24/02/2014 14:06:20
Event ID:      4776
Task Category: Credential Validation
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Audit Success
User:          N/A
Computer:      CDF-BAK-BAK-08
Description:
The computer attempted to validate the credentials for an account.

Authentication Package: MICROSOFT_AUTHENTICATION_PACKAGE_V1_0
Logon Account:  NSUK
Source Workstation: CDF-SHL-MBX-01
Error Code: 0x0

Log Name:      Security
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
Date:          24/02/2014 14:06:20
Event ID:      4624
Task Category: Logon
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Audit Success
User:          N/A
Computer:      CDF-BAK-BAK-08
Description:
An account was successfully logged on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:       0x0

Logon Type:         3

Impersonation Level:        Impersonation

New Logon:
    Security ID:        CDF-BAK-BAK-08\nsuk
    Account Name:       nsuk
    Account Domain:     CDF-BAK-BAK-08
    Logon ID:       0x1D205DE69
    Logon GUID:     {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

Process Information:
    Process ID:     0x0
    Process Name:       -

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   CDF-SHL-MBX-01
    Source Network Address: 172.20.69.3
    Source Port:        5528

Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      NtLmSsp 
    Authentication Package: NTLM
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   NTLM V2
    Key Length:     128

This event is generated when a logon session is created. It is generated on the computer that was accessed.

The subject fields indicate the account on the local system which requested the logon. This is most commonly a service such as the Server service, or a local process such as Winlogon.exe or Services.exe.

The logon type field indicates the kind of logon that occurred. The most common types are 2 (interactive) and 3 (network).

The New Logon fields indicate the account for whom the new logon was created, i.e. the account that was logged on.

The network fields indicate where a remote logon request originated. Workstation name is not always available and may be left blank in some cases.

The impersonation level field indicates the extent to which a process in the logon session can impersonate.

The authentication information fields provide detailed information about this specific logon request.
    - Logon GUID is a unique identifier that can be used to correlate this event with a KDC event.
    - Transited services indicate which intermediate services have participated in this logon request.
    - Package name indicates which sub-protocol was used among the NTLM protocols.
    - Key length indicates the length of the generated session key. This will be 0 if no session key was requested.
```

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok. I've now set up the backup on the second DAG member. This has been running for a week or more and is doing the job sufficiently.